# Can Chrome/Firefox plugins be invoked by random Web Request?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-plugin

I have a question about plugins in Chrome/Firefox browsers. Is it possible for Chrome/Firefox plugins to be invoked by some random Web Request other than `embed` or `object` tags in html?

For example, a page has a web request with MIME jpeg, the browser captures the downloaded raw image data and sends the data to a newly created plugin instance. Is this scene I describe here possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins are used:

- with the mentioned object/embed tags
- as handlers for full page content (e.g. seen with PDFs)

Outside of those scenarios, plugins are not used to handle any content/requests.

Answer (score -1):

Some proxy plugins have did what you want, such as FoxyProxy, Proxy SwitchySharp, etc.